# vaildations in PromptOptions class of botframework

Tags: botframework

I have waterfall style dialog and I am using PromptOptions to prompt user for an input and if in case the input is wrong, I use retry prompt to notify the user that input is wrong. For example:

```
step_context.prompt('dialog_name', prompt = PromptOptions(prompt = 'Please enter your age', retry_prompt = 'Age should be greater than zero'))
```

To verify the input, I use custom validator which I can pass when adding this dialog to dialog set. For example:

```
self.add_dialog(NumberPrompt('dialog_name', Validator))
```

My question is `PromptOptions` has an optional argument called `validations` to which I can pass objects. What is that argument used for? Can that be used to pass my `validator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, `validations` is part of `PromptOptions`. Since your validator can access the prompt options as part of the `PromptValidatorContext`, you can access the validations through the prompt options in your validator.

The validations are not used by the SDK and there is no predefined purpose for them. You can use them however you wish.